# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this error is quite common i tried solutions from those answers but the results were same

So i have 3 Python files, that can be called by users input. My code looks like this

(MAIN)First File

```
class main:
    #random code here

class testo:
   def steve(self):
       obs = input ('Enter : ')
       if obs == 'P':
           import second
           second()
       elif obs == 'N':
           import third
           third()
obj=testo()
obj.seteve()
```

Second File

```
class main:
   #random code here
class llama:
   def clear_text(text):
       sam = input ('Enter : ')
       if sam == 'X':
           from first import steve
       elif sam == 'N':
           import third
           third()
obj=llama()
```

third file (getting error in this file)

```
class ender:
   def draco(text):
       cin = input ('Enter : ')
       if cin == 'X':
           from first import steve
       elif cin == 'T':
           print ('testing')
       else:
           print('nope')
obj = ender()
obj.draco()
```

My first and second files are running good they can call each other good.

But when i try to call my third file from main and type anything and hit enter it throws me this error.

```
  File "first.py", line 136, in <module>
    obj.steve()
  File "file.py", line 111, in steve
    third()   # calling third file
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: What are you trying to do when you call `second()` or `third()`

Comment: scarping some websites i didn't included it here cuz the code would have quite been long thats why i only included error lines

Comment: It is not possible to import and then call a module like that:
```import third;
third()```

instead, you should do something like that:
```import third;
obj = third.ender()```

You can instantiate a class from the third module, but not to call the module itself.

Comment: But what does it mean to you, to call a module? are you trying to run the entire code inside the module or are there functions defined with the same name as the modules?

Comment: @sad_whale3, why do you need to have everything on separate classes? Couldn't you just add new methods to your `steve` class?